# VHDL: Signal assignment question

Tags: vhdl

TLDR: The specific ordering question I'm asking is:

1. Suppose the output depends on some intermediate signals
2. Suppose the intermediate signals depend on some input signals
3. Suppose an input signal changes
4. This may make more than one intermediate signal change
5. The timing of signal assignment is not stringently specified
6. If the output signal generation function observes one of the intermediate signals as having changed before the other intermediate signals having changed, a "transient" output may be generated until the change in the second intermediate signal is observed.
7. Does VHDL guarantee that this does not happen? If so, how?

Reading through the Free Range VHDL book, on page 37, there is a code snippet that is claimed to be equivalent to the code snippet on page 36:

```
-- library declaration
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
-- entity
entity my_ckt_f3 is
port ( L,M,N : in std_logic;
F3 : out std_logic);
end my_ckt_f3;
-- architecture
architecture f3_2 of my_ckt_f3 is
begin
F3<=((NOT L)AND(NOT M)AND N)OR(L AND M);
end f3_2;
```

versus:

```
-- library declaration
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
-- entity
entity my_ckt_f3 is
port ( L,M,N : in std_logic;
F3 : out std_logic);
end my_ckt_f3;
-- architecture
architecture f3_1 of my_ckt_f3 is
signal A1, A2 : std_logic; -- intermediate signals
begin
A1 <= ((NOT L) AND (NOT M) AND N);
A2 <= L AND M;
F3 <= A1 OR A2;
end f3_1;
```

But! The description in the text claims that signals are delayed assignment ("some time" after) and timing or ordering is not guaranteed.

In my mind, this translates to approximately something like "the right side is sampled on clock-rising, and the left side is written on clock-falling," although I'm sure different implementations are actually used in reality.

Now, assuming that each <= operator in a logic chain introduces a time delay of undetermined amount, why are these two snippets equivalent? Couldn't it be that the second implementation, with temporary signals, temporarily outputs some logic value that is not actually the result of any combination of the inputs that it has seen?

I guess I'd like a more formal understanding of what the "signal assignment" really means for timing and outputs. Are compilers guaranteed to "optimize" or "short circuit" temporary signal assignments so that the end result will always be the same as if I wrote the logic expression on a single line?

Comment: I searched the book for "delayed assignment" but didn't find it.  Where does it say this?  BTW, the entities are functionally equivalent, and clock has nothing to do with it (this is purely combinational).

Comment: You are questioning beyond the scope of the particular book. In general you shouldn't try to manufacture scenarios where the poorly conveyed description can be rationalized. Try googling for "VHDL simulation cycle".  VHDL uses delta simulation cycles to emulate concurrency which do not involve the advancement of simulation time. See [31_DeltaTime_Concept.pdf](http://dea.unsj.edu.ar/sda/31_DeltaTime_Concept.pdf) for example. Note it's likely your simulator has a maximum number of delta cycles before incurring simulation time advance, blocking it's use from general purpose parallel computing.

Comment: @Koontz: This seems like a good answer -- or, to answer the baser question I have; is this a resaonable statement? "Yes, the tools will forward signal assignment in an optimal fashion to make the two cases equivalent."

There is still a question on ordering, though -- see clarification at the bottom.

Comment: @apalopohapa: At the bottom of page 24, it says this: 'A variable changes its value
soon after the variable assignment is executed. Instead, a signal changes
its value "some time" after the signal assignment expression is evaluated.'

Comment: There's a difference in the number of delta cycles between the two versions based on having more signal targets resulting in more signals on the right hand side of signal assignments. They are guaranteed to be the equivalent when simulation time advances. And no, compilers don't play games with signal assignments. Concurrent statements are translated into equivalent processes for simulation, optimization is generally not possible across process boundaries - every signal can be visible to a waveform display. Neither Free Range VHDL nor this forum are a replacement for authoritative references.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight. I'm a complete newbie to VHDL and hardware synthesis. The fact that, 10% into a supposedly beginner book, I have to go to "authoritative references," is lamentable. It's like asking a C++ newbie to go look something up in the standards document :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering about how the <= operator works; it is what is called a 'nonblocking assignment.'  What this means is that the left hand side of all of the <= are performed for a particular event (e.g. rising clock edge) and then once those are all evaluated, the result is placed in the output.  This allows you to write shift registers without temporary variables.  None of the values change until the left hand calculations are completed, then the results are moved over to the right hand side.  It is generally not a good idea to use nonblocking assignments for combinatorial logic.  Generally they are only used to create latches and registers and you use regular blocking assignments for combinatorial logic.  When synchronized with a clock signal, you can generally consider <= operations to be D flip-flops that sample the input and transfer it to the output atomically on a single clock edge.

'Race conditions' where intermediate indeterminate results appear on the outputs of combinatorial functions are hard to avoid and they can depend greatly on how the design is actually implemented on an ASIC or FPGA.  However, most designs are synchronous and so as long as the output settles within one clock period this is not a problem.  There are tools that can check the timing performance of a design to check all of the path delays to ensure that the results will always be valid for a given clock frequency, but this is highly dependent not on the actual HDL code but on the way the design is placed and routed.

Synthesizers (not compilers!!!!) will generally perform optimization on combinatorial logic.  There are limits to how much the synthesizer can do (e.g. it will not re-architect your system) so you have to know more or less how it will end up being implemented.  If you're working on an FPGA, generally the synthesis and place and route will pack any logic function that fits onto LUTs.  So if you can separate out a single logic function with up to 4 inputs and 1 output, this will end up on a single LUT and the only delay that matters is the propagation delay of the LUT, which is the same for all of its inputs.  In the case of your example function, both pieces of code may be implemented identically on one LUT with three inputs and one output.

Comment: So, if I combine this answer, with the discussion about delta time above, I think I have a complete picture. Just to be clear, before I accept this answers: Combinatoric logic that has different number of steps on different inputs may have temporary "races" that will, during simulation, only be visible during delta time, not during "all cascaded events complete" time. Whether some hardware sees those fluctuations or not after synthesis would be implementation dependent -- perhaps it happens, perhaps not?

Comment: Pretty much.  Delta time is more of a simulation artifact.  Unless you're doing transistor level simulation, the results are not going to accurately represent what goes on in a final implementation, and that will be highly dependent on the place and route stage and not just synthesis.

Comment: (Being pedantic) Non-blocking is really applicable to Verilog. VHDL doesn't have the concept per-se. If I read the question right, the OP is talking about determinism. VHDL has what it calls "delta cycles". The first phase is signal value updates. In the second phase these processes are evaluated. "In these processes, signals assignments may occur that schedule value updates in the next delta cycle." A great explanation is: http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel